# Json.net deserialization creates null object

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm using json.net to serialize/deserialize a dictionary. The problem is that on deserialization some objects are re-created as null. This only happens when using PreserveReferenceHandling. Code:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        data["Roles"] = (from r in Roles
                        select new { Id = r.Id, Name = r.Name }).ToList();

        data["CompanyCourses"] = (from cvc in CompanyVideoCourses
                                  where cvc.Company.Id == location.Company.Id
                                  select cvc).ToList();

        data["VideoCourses"] = (from vc in VideoCourses
                                select vc).ToList();

        data["CompanyCourses"] = (from cvc in CompanyVideoCourses
                                  where cvc.Company.Id == location.Company.Id
                                  select cvc).ToList();
        data["Location"] = location;

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings {                                                                                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects});


        Dictionary<string, object> newdata = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        newdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(output,
            new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
        JArray roles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(newdata["Roles"].ToString());

        //problem 1 here
        List<VideoCourse> videoCourses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VideoCourse>>(newdata["VideoCourses"].ToString());

        //problem 2 here
        List<CompanyVideoCourse> companyCourses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompanyVideoCourse>>(newdata["CompanyCourses"].ToString());
        Location location1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(newdata["Location"].ToString());
```

Problem variant 1 - The system has Video Courses. Each company can be assigned multiple courses. In this test half the available courses are assigned to the company. When the VideoCourses are deserialized any course that is *not* assigned to the company is null.

Problem variant 2 - if I change the order of dictionary creation by putting the line starting `data["CompanyCourses"] =` after the line `data["VideoCourses"] =` then when `List<CompanyVideoCourse> companyCourses = ...` is executed the VideoCourse property is null (this is a join table with additional data).

Problem variants 1 and 2 are dependent on the ordering of the dictionary. If one happens the other does not.

I've checked the generated json and all of the $id and $ref values look good. As stated above this is only an issue if PreserveReferencesHandling is used. If it isn't used then everything works as expected, no matter in which order the dictionary is created.

So the question is: how do I get all of my objects recreated?

### Update

Here is an example of the generated json that exhibits the problem.

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "CompanyCourses": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Company": {
        "$id": "3",
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Company0",
        "Address": "123 e main",
        "ContactName": "Joe Contact",
        "ContactPhone": "2065551212",
        "ContactEmail": "joec@contactcompany.com",
        "Maritime_Id": "19360"
      },
      "VideoCourse": {
        "$id": "4",
        "InternetLocation": "5QyZRnYt",
        "SKU": "DVD0-18",
        "FileName": "Access-Control.mp4",
        "CoverFileName": "Access-Control-Cover.png",
        "PosterFileName": "Access-Control-Poster.png",
        "VTTFileName": "Access-Control.vtt",
        "RunningTime": "00:14:00",
        "Id": 11,
        "Name": "Access Control: Threat Awareness and Prevention",
        "Description": "<p>Understand and prevent the threat of unauthorized access to your ship.</p>\r\n                             <p>Topics:</p>\r\n                             <ul>\r\n                             <li>Risk recognition</li>\r\n                             <li>Piracy and hijacking prevention</li>\r\n                             <li>The threat of unauthorized access</li>\r\n                             <li>Security and team-effort approach</li>\r\n                             <li>Controlling shipboard access in port</li>\r\n                             </ul>",
        "Repeating": false,
        "Interval": 0,
        "Keywords": "ISPS"
      },
      "Id": 1,
      "Corporate_Id": null
    }
  ],
  "Location": {
    "$id": "14",
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "ShipatSea Location0",
    "Address": null,
    "Company": {
      "$ref": "3"
    }
  }
}
```

When this is deserialized the "Company" property in the "Location" object is null even though the $id $ref points to ("3") exists at the top.

Comment: If you already know the solution (don't use preserve reference handling) then why are you asking the question? Do you know what the property does? I'm pretty sure it has no purpose in your code above. It's only necessary for recursive structures. Is this supposed to be some kind of an exercise? That code is useless...

Comment: PreserveReferenceHandling greatly reduces the size of the resulting json because there are, in fact, circular references involved. I would much prefer to use it.

Comment: Alright well I don't think the question can really be answered without knowing; 1) the format of the json and 2) the values for each key in `data` after each of those LINQ queries executes. For example, the cause of problem variant 2 is almost certainly related to those LINQ queries and has nothing to do with json.NET.

Comment: I don't believe the LINQ statements are the issue. After all, whether problem 1 or problem 2 happens depends on the order the LINQ statements are executed. Clearly Json.NET can deal with them as an input. The question why some objects are not deserialized. I'll post an example of the json.

Comment: Not sure why someone -1'd this. As the SO FAQ clearly states, it's perfectly OK to post a question when you already know the answer. It helps grow the overall body of knowledge of SO. I'm gonna +1 this post so that the original poster is not penalized for asking a question that falls safely within our guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be serializing each part of the dictionary before serializing the entire dictionary. That way when each dictionary value is deserialized it has all the information it needs to stand on its own. So, for example, this:

```
 data["Location"] = location;
```

becomes

```
data["Location"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(location, new JsonSerializerSettings { 
             PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
         });
```